# Join two sql statements in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to,

```
Class  City
01      xx
02      xx   
03      yy  
04      zz
```

And the result I want is like, (select Class and Count of City where city = xx or city = yy )

```
Class  Count
01      2 
02      2 
03      1
04      0
```

The one I can't understand how to do is getting the mismatching rows into the result as well. In this example the last row of Class 04.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below SQL:

```
SELECT t1.class, count(t2.class) AS COUNT FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.city=t2.city AND t1.city in ('xx', 'yy')
GROUP BY t1.class, t1.city;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ddf07/1/0)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by aggregating to get the count and then joining back the result:

```
select t.class, tc.cnt    
from table t join
     (select t.class, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by class
     ) tc
     on tc.class = t.class;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
create table #cc (class int ,city varchar(2))
insert into #cc values (1,'xx')
insert into #cc values (2,'xx')
insert into #cc values (3,'yy')
insert into #cc values (4,'zz')
--insert into #cc values (1,'xx')


select class,isnull(c.cnt,0)
from #cc cc
left join (select city ,count(city) as cnt 
            from #cc c where city in ('xx','yy') 
            group by city ) c on c.city = cc.city
```

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your purpose:

SELECT TableMain.Class, TableJoin.CityCount
FROM TableMain 
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as CityCount, Class FROM TableMain GROUP BY City) TableJoin
ON TableJoin.Class = TableMain.class;